# htaccess to strip WWW from domain *and* any subdirectories

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Am running the above code and it strips the www when you go to http://www.mydomain.com   but how do I get it to also strip the www when you go to a subdirectory, etc http://www.mydomain.com/users ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to enable

```
RewriteLog "yourLogFile"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

to get some more information about what is going on ...